# How can I get a Windows execuable's "Original Filename" details field using cmd/batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

On windows, MZ/PE executables often have an attibute called "Original File Name", used to describe the original file name assigned to an executable file when it was created.

It is readable to a Windows user from the "Details" tab of the file's "Properties" window (opened by rightclicking a file and selecting "Properties").

I found many other questions that discuss "original file name, so to make it clear, I'm talking about this field, for the mspaint.exe file:

[image: In memory of it's announced death, I hope the gesture will be appreciated :)]

I however, whould like to access/read this attribute (and potentially edit it) using batch files or the windows command line (not powershell, please!).

Thanks!

Comment: There is no built-in way of doing this only using batch files. The information is stored in a "StringFileInfo" section of the version resource and the field is named "OriginalFilename". If you google for "command-line version resource editor" you should be able to find appropriate tools.

Comment: Thank you for the response, @zett42!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does not have a built-in command line tool to read version information from PE files.

You can use a resource editor like [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to export information but you still have to parse the exported file.

On WinVista+ (and WinXP with desktop search installed) you can read the information using the shell property system (the same API used by the file properties dialog).

A Microsoft developer has created a free tool called [shellproperty.exe](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matthew_van_eerde/2013/09/24/shellproperty-exe-v2-read-all-properties-on-a-file-set-properties-of-certain-non-vt_lpwstr-types/) that you can use to read the `System.OriginalFileName` property.

With Windows Script Host it is also possible to access the property system if you use the [ShellFolderItem.ExtendedProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774055(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

And finally, a WSH script can be merged with a batch file to create a working [polyglot](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170804-00/?p=96765) with zero external dependencies:

```
@if (1 == 0) @end /*
@cscript.exe /E:jscript /nologo "%~f0" %*
@goto :eof
*/

var objShell = new ActiveXObject("shell.application");
var objFolder2, ssfSysDir = 0x25, propVal = "";
objFolder2 = objShell.NameSpace(ssfSysDir);
if (objFolder2 != null)
{
    var objFolderItem;
    objFolderItem = objFolder2.ParseName("mspaint.exe");
    if (objFolderItem != null)
    {
        propVal = objFolderItem.ExtendedProperty("{0CEF7D53-FA64-11D1-A203-0000F81FEDEE},6");
        WScript.Echo(propVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you perhaps explain slightly more details how the merged WSH & batch script works? how the merging works out, how to run those scripts, etc...

Comment: The first 4 lines as a batch file just executes cscript.exe with its own filename and then quits. The first 4 lines as a WSH file is a "do nothing" If branch and a comment to skip the batch code. You just save it as a .cmd file and run it as a normal batch file.

Comment: Cool. thanks. I'll let the question sit for a bit and then accept it if nothing better comes.